# Не срабатывает ajax запрос

Tags: php, html

Есть скрипт на сервере tings.php который принимает значение id, проверяет обновилась ли новость, если да, то выдает информацию, если нет, то оставляет все как есть.
А на сайте выводится информация. Допустим новости с id = 1,id = 2,id = 3 и т.п.
У каждой новости есть кнопка refresh. Нужно, не обновляя страницу, обновить содержимое выбранной новости.

```
<div onClick="taskreload({id новости}); return false;" class="block_update"></div>
<div id="taskload{id новости}">Новость с id = 1 (Содержимое блока) </div>
```

Помогите написать ajax обработчик, который бы отсылал id новости в tings.php и в зависимости от ответа обновлял блок с `div.id=taskload{id новости}`.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с использованием `jQuery`:

```
function taskreload(id) {
    $.get('/tings.php', {
        id: id
    }, function(response) {
        $('#taksload' + id).text(response);
    });
}
```